# Проблема русификации программы exe

Tags: windows-7, exe, окно, перевод, русификация

Коротко говоря: нужно "залипить" изображение поверх приложения.

Не коротко:
Есть приложение *.exe, которое я так понимаю зашифровано. Понял я это по многочисленных попытках русификации разными программами: Resource Hacker, ResHack, Restorator, eXeScope, LikeRusXP, Multilizer, WinMerge. Так и не смог русифицировать. Программы выдавали не полные значения такие как: иконка и манифест.

Я не особо знающий в программировании. Может есть какое нибудь приложение, которое может русифицировать сжатое или зашифрованное *.exe.

Есть такие плагины типа "мгновенный перевод поверх окна". Такое не надо.

Нужна прога, которая быстро изменяет зашифрованное exe приложение или которая не переводит, а заменяет интерфейс поверх окна приложения. Причем не автоматикой, а вручную создавать пункты перевода, которые должны отобразиться. Например через dll библиотеки.

Ни за что не поверю, что в эру информационных технологий люди не придумали приложение, которое не меняет логику exe, а просто создает "картинку" поверх нее, как русификатор. Чтобы при движении, закрытии-открытии, сворачивании окна все оставалось.

Нужно чтобы переводилось абсолютно любые приложения на OS Windows 7.
Не имеет значения на каком языке программирования написана эта *.exe, которую нужно перевести.

Например, чтобы можно было тыкнуть на переведенный участок, а windows подумал, что я будто тыкнул на саму кнопку на нижнем слое.

Пример:

[image: Пример]

Comment: @gbg Я это и хочу сказать. Не нужно модифицировать программу, нужно только просто перевести текст. Не через гугл транслейт, а самим написать перевод, и всклеить его поверх приложения, не модифицируя его. Не думаю, что у таких простых программ есть функция отслеживания типа "сработала самозащита" как у касперского, которое предотвращает наложение. Не нужно создавать программу для автоматического перевода. Нужно типа создать ватермарку, только не поверх фото, а поверх приложения, которая будет двигаться вместе с ним. Не думаю, что эту программу можно вскрыть. Она по сути - чит.

Comment: @gbg нет, для любых. Те как. Для каждого, но вручную подбирать перевод. Долго капался в инете, нашел какой то EpicPen, который рисует поверх окон. Но это не то. Нужно чтобы текст был еще и подвязан к самой программе.

Answer (score 1):

Постараюсь покороче объяснить, почему разработка такой универсальной программы потребует огромных бюджетов, причем в уях.

Самое простое, это когда авторы программы сами позаботились о том, чтобы эту программу можно было переводить. В таком случае, все сообщения, выводимые программой, хранятся где-то в виде шаблонных строк. Что такое шаблон - это вот такая штука "Скопировано %1 файлов" "%1 files copied". Как видите, в зависимости от языка, может меняться порядок следования слов в предложении, что и требует введения таких вот шаблонов.

Чтобы шаблоны работали, они должны храниться и обрабатываться программой как строки в мультибайтном юникоде, иначе переводы на диалекты азиатских языков, скорее всего, сломаются.

В этом случае, мы для перевода берем редактор языковых файлов (типа poedit - стандарт переводов для линукса и опенсорса) и переводим. 
Либо редактором ресурсов пробуем ковырять шаблоны, если они в ресурсах exe.

Если же авторы программы против умников, которые хотят эту программу модифицировать, то увы, я вам не советчик - ищите сами способы нарушить лицензию.

Что тут может пойти не так? Например, если авторы программы все же хранят шаблоны, но забили на кодировки, на русский вы переведете, а вот на диалекты китайского - нет, тут юникод нужен.

Ваша же идея с тем, чтобы распознавать на экране окно интересующей вас программы и модифицировать его, также упирается в две проблемы - как правило, переведенные строки являются шаблонами, ну а на этапе вывода у вас уже не будет информации о том, где в данной строке шаблон, а где - подставленные значения - переводилка будет работать не всегда корректно. И вторая - лицензия на программу может прямо запрещать вмешательство в ее работу.

Тут видно два варианта вмешательства - подменять программе вызовы API Windows по рисованию текста в окне - это когда программа командует "задай текст вон в том поле brown fox", а переводилка должна на лету подставить новый текст,и при этом она должна точно сообразить, какое поле переводят, короче, вынос мозга.

Либо второй вариант - заменять тексты в уже отрисованном окне, но тут также будет задница, потому что окно могут проскроллить, длина перевода может быть не та, что у оригинала, короче, куча вариантов того, как все может пойти не так, которые надо корректно разрулить, что накручивает нолики в счетчике бюджета.

А просто распознавать весь видимый текст, скармливать его гугл транслейту и вклеивать обратно в гуй конечно можно, но качество такого "перевода" будет тошнотворным.

Comment: я это и хочу сказать. Не нужно модифицировать программу, нужно только просто перевести текст. Не через гугл транслейт, а самим написать перевод, и всклеить его поверх приложения, не модифицируя его. Не думаю, что у таких простых программ есть функция отвлеживания  типа "сработала самозащита" как у касперского, которое предотвращает наложение.

Comment: Для одного конкретного приложения?